# Create JSON object from form fields

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a portion of a larger JSON object to send to an API. The portion of the JSON object I need to create in the variable needs to be formatted like this:

```
{   
 "name": "email",
 "value": "example@example.com"
},
{   
 "name": "firstname",
 "value": "Jeff"
}, 
etc...
```

Initially I used the following (form the tutorial I was following for form validation) to create the object:

```
 const formObject = Array.from(formElement.elements)
        .filter(element => element.type !== 'submit' )
        .reduce((accumulator, element) => ({ ...accumulator, [element.name] : element.value}), {});
```

This worked looping through the fields and creating an object, but obviously was in the wrong format.

In my JS, I've tried a bunch of ways to edit the code to formate the object correctly. The closest I've got is this, but it only creates one value and then stops:

```
const formObject = Array.from(formElement.elements)
    .filter(element => element.type !== 'submit' )
    .reduce((accumulator, element) => ({ ...accumulator, "name":element.name, "value":element.value}), {});
```

How can I fix it please?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Are you sure it's not meant to be an array (`[ {...}, {...} ]`) instead?

Comment: Have you tried the [`FormData API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)? [Here's some more information](https://www.learnwithjason.dev/blog/get-form-values-as-json).

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Thank you. This is only a section of a larger object. I will reformat the question.

Comment: Your expected result is an array of objects, but you have a `reduce` at the end that aggregates the values to one object. Please read the tag descriptions before you use a tag. The JSON tag contains: _"Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals."_ JSON is a text format.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved it by asking Chat GPT.

I passed in my formObject variable to this and it delivered the required output:

```
const jsonPayload = Object.keys(formObject).map((key) => ({
    name: key,
    value: formObject[key],
}))
```

I then added the jsonPayload into the larger JSON object and it was accepted by the API.